# How to calculate "amount" of color component in an RGB color

Tags: objective-c, c, colors, rgb

I wanted to perform a simple image analyses where I determine which portion of an image corresponds to a certain "control color range". I have reduced the image to a 2D pixel map containing RGB values but now I'm stuck trying to determine how much red, for example is contained in a certain pixel.

I know so little about color I'm having difficult time even finding the correct terms to use to start my search. Is there a simple formula to calculate the average or majority of an RGB component (the control color) that is contained in an RGB color? The goal is provide a control color and percent of it's amount that exists so I can filter it out from the other colors in the pixel map (i.e this pixel is 80% red).

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Did you checked the Color.GetHue function / HSV system instead of the RGB values ?

Comment: Could you show some of your code what you have already done?

Comment: I didn't know how to use hue so I didn't consider it yet. NSColor provides a way to retrieve hue but it was really costly in terms of time/CPU and memory allocation. I think this could be calculated more efficiently if I knew it was needed.

Comment: I don't have any code relevant to the problem yet, just RGB values like 255, 80, 0 etc... The problem is not related to any one specific language even.

Comment: Based on your comment to the answer below, HSB is _exactly_ what you want. The Hue component is what you're trying to measure. You will just end up beating your head against a wall trying to determine "how yellow" a particular color expressed as RGB is. Hue describes exactly that -- it's an angle around a continuous color wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.

Load your image into an RGB color array.

Check each entry of the array to find the largest amount of color in that pixel.

Here is a little diagram of what I am trying to explain.

| R | G | B |
| 0 | 1 |255|

Going through you see that blue is the closest number to 255. Add it to an integer.

`int r = 0;`
`int g = 0;`
`int b = 0;`

`b = b + 1;`

When you are done analyzing each entry in the array check to see what color is the closest to 255.

`r = 255 - r;`
`g = 255 - r;`
`b = 255 - r;`

Compare each value to find the largest number.

And their you go.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I think this will determine the average for the entire image but I'm trying to determine if a single RGB color meets the threshold for a certain amount of color. For example 255, 10, 10 is really red but 255, 190, 92 is more yellow. How do I know the first value is the red one because both of the red components are 255.

Comment: yes this code will find it for the entire image. In order to find out if its more yellowish then you would need some kind of database. Or you would need a minimum and maximum value for yellow. What your trying to accomplish will not be something that can be done in a day but more like weeks. How about a like for at least giving you code for the entire image ;)